# Changing git setup to allow multiple users to push/commit files

Tags: git, github, beagleboard

I've got a beaglebone that I set up a while back (when I was first learning git) with an ssh key for a specific github account. That account is our company's main account. Many people work directly on, and push to github directly from, the beaglebone. I'd like to change the settings so that whenever someone wants to commit or push to github they are queried for their username.

My most recent commit and push looks like this... you'll see I have no option to enter a username, just the password for our company's main account.

```
root@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9/pypos# git commit -a -m "class restructured and passing the new updated test script"
[class_restructure 1db2e33] class restructured and passing the new updated test script
 2 files changed, 14 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)
root@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9/pypos# git push origin class_restructure
Enter passphrase for key '/home/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 7, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 531 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:FarmDesign/pypos.git
   83831a8..1db2e33  class_restructure -> class_restructure
root@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9/pypos#
```

Answer (score 3):

GitHub supports different protocols for communicating with the repositories you have hosted there. If you use the SSH protocol, then git asks you for the password to unlock the key stored in .ssh which is tied to the ability to push to the GitHub repo (anyone with access to the key can push to the repo, so providing the password for accessing the key is all that is needed). However, if you use HTTP, you will be asked for your GitHub username and password.

So, go to the GitHub webpage of your repository and notice the HTTP, SSH and GIT toggle buttons next to the URL of the repository (near the top of the page). Play around with that button to see how the URL of the repo changes -- these are the different URLs at which your repo is accessible depending on which protocol you are using. Now, click on "HTTP" and copy that URL to clipboard.

Now, go to your terminal and cd to the directory of your local clone of the repo. Now, use the git remote command to change the URL at which git will be communicating with the GitHub repo:

```
git remote set-url origin THE_URL_THAT_YOU_JUST_COPIED_TO_CLIPBOARD
```

Now when you try to do git push, git will use the HTTP protocol which will require you to specify your username and password.

Comment: Unforunately I was having difficulty settings up an https (it's a private repository), which is why I went with an SSH key...am I to understand that using multiple users on the same machine is impossible via ssh?

Comment: You should be able to set up HTTPS for a private repository. I have private repos and have no trouble with using HTTPS. However, you have to add other GitHub users as a collaborator to the repo for them to be able to access the repo over HTTPS.

As for using SSH keys and multiple users -- yes, it is possible to have multiple users on the same machine and use SSH. It is possible if the ssh keys for each user are stored in a separate user account. However, I noticed that you are using ssh keys from the root account (see your question, line `Enter passphrase for key '/home/root/.ssh/id_rsa':`).